# How to deploy multiple serverless.yml files one after another(sequentially)

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have created multiple **Serverless.yml(like serverless1.yml, serverless2.yml... so on)** files, I am able to deploy one by one using cd with going back to each folder, but I want to deploy the stacks one after another in sequential order using a single sevrerless.yml or shell script file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a bash script for deploying stacks one after another(Sequentially).